# Transfer from one PC to another so I can listen to the sound on the other PC

Tags: windows-10, audio-streaming, digital-audio

I'm desperate, so I turn to you folks ...

Has anyone else already solved the problem?

I have two computers ...

The first and the game:
MB: Msi mag Z390 Tomahawk
WIN: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
CPU: Intel Core i9 9900k
GPU: Msi Geforce 2070 Gaming Z 8G 8Gb GDDR6
RAM: Corsair Vengeance Black 16Gb DDR4 3000Mhz
PSU: Seasonic S12II-620 620W
SSD1: Samsung SSD 960 EVO (M.2) - 250GB
SSD2: Samsung SSD 970 EVO PLUS (M.2) - 500GB
HDD1: Seagate BarraCuda - 2TB
HDD2: Seagate BarraCuda - 2TB
CASE: Be quiet! Silent Base 801
MONITOR: LG 34UC89G-B - LED monitor 34"
CPU COLER: NZXT Kraken X72
SOUND CARD: Creative Sound Blaster ZX
HEADPHONES: Logitech G231 Prodigy*
REPRO: Redstar RS-501 5.1
WHEEL: Logitech G29 + Shifter*

The second and streaming:
MB: ASRock B450M PRO4
WIN: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
CPU: Amd Ryzen 7 2700X
GPU: Msi Geforce 1070 Gaming X 8G 8Gb
RAM: Corsair Vengeance Black 16Gb DDR4 3000Mhz
PSU: Seasonic S12II-620 620W
SSD: Samsung SSD 960 EVO (M.2) - 250GB
HDD: Seagate BarraCuda - 2TB
CASE: Be quiet! Silent Base 801
MONITOR1: Acer Nitro VG270bmiix - LED monitor 27"
MONITOR2: Acer Nitro VG270bmiix - LED monitor 27"
CPU COLER: Be quiet! Dark Rock PRO 4
SOUND CARD: Creative Sound Blaster ZX
EDITINGCARD: Elgato Game Capture 4K60 Pro
WEBCAM1: Logitech Webcam C922 Pro Stream
WEBCAM2: Logitech Webcam C922 Pro Stream
WEBCAM3: Creative Live! Cam Sync HD
MICROPHONE1: Behringer C-1U
MICROPHONE2: Behringer C-1U
HEADPHONES1: Logitech G231 Prodigy
HEADPHONES2: Logitech G231 Prodigy
GREENSCREEN: Elgato Green Screen

And I need to get the sound from the gaming PC to streaming.

Currently I have both computers connected by fiber optic cable with the fact that on streaming computer I have only wiretapping from SPDIF-Out to Speakers and that is why I can hear the game too (AND THAT IS MY PROBLEM HERE) because it sometimes happens to me for several seconds there will be some robotic sound and the stream tends to hang. !

Built-in sound card off on both computers in bios (maybe that's good)
On the streaming PC I use Voicemeeter + two virtual cables but this probably won't because I reinstalled the windows yesterday and tried it without it and the problem persisted. I tried everything and so I suspect my sound card the problem was never a problem if the computers were connected via 3.5 jacks using integrated cards.

Otherwise, as I wrote ... Without running OBS Studio I do not have a sound problem on any PC

So does anyone have any advice on what to do or how to connect computers?
I also suspect that it probably does just the bugging that I need to hear the game content from the gaming PC

Answer (score 0):

seems like an obs issue, and not you, the only way to fix it is to suggest it, or if your really desperate, add it into obs yourself. Theres no other choice that i can see...

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thank you for your reaction ...
What I am trying now is that I reinstalled my windows on the streaming computer and used the older version and v1607 because maybe I read somewhere that the current version of windows v1903 has perhaps some sound problems so I try this option.

Today I was streaming for an hour and a half and everything was going well which unfortunately does not mean that it will work just as well tomorrow but all this week I intend to test this version of windows.

For version v1903 I tried the older version of Obs Studio and this way did not lead!

Then I just think that could be the only mistake on the side of the manufacturer of sound cards that I have, whether hardware or software but if it is so I really do not know what to do with it.

For me, Voicemeeter and its features are extremely important because I need to have each application separately.